# Set custom timeout to Bluetooth-le write with Quasar-Framework/Capacitor

Tags: vue.js, bluetooth-lowenergy, capacitor, quasar-framework, capacitor-plugin

I'm using the [Bluetooth-LE](https://github.com/capacitor-community/bluetooth-le#write) community plugin in a Quasar/Capacitor project.

Since version 1.7.0, we can make timeouts configurable. But how? I need help with the syntax. Can someone give me a fonctionnal example with a custom timeout.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was also looking for that information. Haven't found any details on the documention but the file 'definitions.d.ts' inside the Bluetooth-LE module.

Try this :

```
    const writeFlag = await BleClient.write(
        device.deviceId, 
        SERV_SYSTEM_SETTINGS, 
        CHAR_RTC, 
        dvDateTime,
        {timeout:(10000)}    //  <---- this is what you need
    );
```